# How do I sort a table with Javascript in alphabetical order with case sensitivity?

Tags: javascript, sorting

No jQuery answers as I don't use it in this site.

I have a table in the general form

```
<tbody><tr><td>2</td><td><a href="http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ah-my-goddess">Ah! My Goddess</a></td></tr></tbody>
```

I need to access the inner text of the 'a' element, and I'm not sure how to do this. I wanted to use querySelectorAll but apparently, because the table is generated by javascript through ajax, I cannot do this. This leads me unsure of how to get to the a element let alone sort its text content, such as 'Ah! My Goddess'. The caveat is there are many more table rows like this, with the same basic pattern.

Comment: You need to create a callback bound to the ajax return call, so that you aren't sorting the table before it's been populated.

Comment: The problem right now is that I don't know how to sort it. If it is indeed what you're saying, I will fix it then but right now, I am confused how to access the a element.

Comment: It is very surprising that no one tried to get element from HTML using pure JavaScript before you... Have you tried to search?

Comment: Yes, I've searched. The problem is how I am trying to access it. Usually it would be no problem with querySelectorAll, I can just divet down to access the correct thing. But that only works with non-live node lists, and this one is live so I have no way to access the correct element (that I can think of).

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery you could try and use the root of the functions that it is based on. Such as for replacing the selectors with:

`document.querySelectorAll('td').textContent`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can refer to the table by id:

```
var t = document.getElementById(/*table id*/);

var d = t.tBodies[0].rows; // is an HTMLCollection, kinda like an array
d = [...t.tBodies[0].rows]; // converts it into an array of rows
```

once it's in an array, you can do array-like things to the rows, like `sort()` them

now, looking at the first row `d[0]` and assuming that the anchor is always in the second column, the anchor can be referred to as:

```
var a = d[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

and the text inside the opening/closing tags is:

```
a.innerHTML; // In this case: 'Ah! My Goddess'
```

putting some of this together, a sort (alphabetically) could be:

```
var byAnchorText = (a, b) => a.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML - b.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
var t = document.getElementById(/*table id*/);
Array.sort.apply(t.tBodies[0].rows, byAnchorText);
```

or something like this, you can fix it up as you see fit.